# What's the smallest ellipsoid enclosing the half-sphere?

Tags: convex-optimization, positive-definite

Let the half-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be defined by
$$
R = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert_2 \leq 1\;\wedge\;x_1 \geq 0\}\,.
$$
Any ellipsoid can be defined using a positive definite matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and a center $\mathbf{a}$. The ellipsoid corresponding to $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ is
$$
E(\mathbf{A,a}) = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \mathbf{(x-a)}^T\mathbf{A(x-a)} \leq 1\}\,.
$$
The question is: for which pair $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{a}$ where $R\subseteq E(\mathbf{A,a})$ is the volume of $E(\mathbf{A,a})$ the smallest? The volume of $E(\mathbf{A,a})$ being given by
$$
\text{Vol}(E(\mathbf{A,a})) = \frac{\text{Vol}(S_n)}{\sqrt{\det \mathbf{A}}}
$$
where $S_n$ is the $n$-dimensional unit hypersphere.

Looking at the formula for the volume of an ellipsoid it's clear that in order to minimize the volume we have to maximize $\det \mathbf{A}$ subject to $R\subseteq E(\mathbf{A,a})$ for some $\mathbf{a}$. Also it might be helpful that maximizing $\det \mathbf{A}$ is equivalent to maximizing $\log (\det \mathbf{A})$ which, as it turns out, is concave on the domain of positive definite matrices.

So far I've been able to find [this exercise](https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/math/operations-research/ifor-dam/documents/Exercises10.pdf) on the topic. However,

1. I'm not sure if this is the easiest way to answer this question or if it's simply using Slater's condition and the KKT conditions because it wants to practice those.
2. The overall structure of the argument is still unclear to me. c) shows that the primal optimum is equal to the dual optimum. And d) shows that the proposed $\overline{\mathbf{A}}$ *might* be an optimum. How does that imply that $\overline{\mathbf{A}}$ indeed *is* the optimum?

Comment: For a convex problem which satisfies strong duality the KKT conditions are equivalent to optimality.

Comment: Do you know a good reference for that?

Comment: Boyd and Vandenberghe "Convex optimization"  sect. 5.5.3 "KKT optimality conditions". Basically the KKT equation is equivalent to the statement that the primal and dual objective values are equal.